# Bash For-Loop: How to compare two array items at different indexes?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm new to bash scripting and trying to compare two items of an array (specifically the $@ parameters). However, I just can't get it to work.

So what I'm specificially trying to do here is using a for loop to go through the $@ array, and compare the array item at index i with the item at index i+1. Unfortunately, ${@[$i]} and ${@[$i+1]} both cause bad substitution errors and I just can't seem to find the solution.

If anyone has an idea how this issue could be solved I'd be very grateful.

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 0; i < ${#@}; i++ )); do
  if (( "${@[$i]}" < "${@[$i+1]}" )); then
    echo "true"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use an actual array. `$@` is not an array, it's special. Also, no need for `${` everywhere.

```
array=("$@")

...
   if (( array[i] < array[i+1] )); then
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue!!

Answer (score 0):

indirect variables can also be used here:

```sh
for ((i=1, j=2; j <= $#; i++, j++)); do
    if (( ${!i} < ${!j} )); then
        echo "$i, $j: true"
    fi
done
```

given

```sh
set -- 2 4 6 8 1 10
```

we get

```
1, 2: true
2, 3: true
3, 4: true
5, 6: true
```

ref: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

---

Or, we can destructively iterate over the positional params:

```sh
prev=$1
shift
while (($# > 0)); do
    curr=$1
    shift
    ((prev < curr)) && echo true
    prev=$curr
done
```